# cpu clock too low / force cpu clock / overclock

Tags: macbook-pro, performance, cpu, temperature, processor

I have a MacBook from a few years back. 
When I use it write some code and browse the internet, the fans go very fast and the noise is horrible. But the temp shows only 70 C.

So I used SMC to force the fans to 3000rpm. I really don't mind frying my MacBook as long as its quiet.
Now instead of the temp rising to 90 C or more (what I want!), my MacBook decides to lower the cpu clock to 0.8 Ghz. And it becomes completely useless. I can't even use one program at a time.
Even the mouse cursor lags.

What can I do? Can I force the CPU clock?

Model: A1286 i7 2.0 Ghz (High Sierra) Early 2011

edit: i don't even want a turbo boost or anything (would be nice). i just want to use the 2 Ghz and not only 0.8 Ghz.

Comment: **be specific** which exact model?

Comment: I am a bit confused. As far as I know you cannot set *maximum* speeds for the fan, only *minimum*. I understand that there is thermal throttling going on. I don't think this can be overruled. There are tools to disable TurboBoost on certain Intel CPUs, which may help a bit to keep the Mac cool.

Comment: @n1000 it is possible using the terminal interface: https://github.com/hholtmann/smcFanControl/tree/master/smc-command
i think you miss-understood my question. i don't want to keep my mac cool. i want it to get really hot and use the full clock speed not just 0.8 ghz.

Comment: @SteveChambers i updated the question.

Comment: There are different temperature sensors. On the CPU, heatsinks, GPU, etc. If any of those hit their upper limit the Mac starts throttling as a last resort. This is what you are seeing. I think this is implemented low-level and I never heard of tools that would allow to override this. However, I also had not know that SMC can set a maximum fan speed :) Curious to see if there are any answers. Another reason that Macs throttle is when the battery is damaged and cannot buffer peak loads anymore. Is your battery ok?

Comment: @n1000 i think my battery is fine for its age. still has at least 2h of capacity.
smc also allowed me to read other temperature sensors and they all showed even lower values than the cpu. somehow i almost suspect apple doing this on purpose. 70 C is a pathetic temperature to start throttling.

Comment: What temperatures does it reach when you disable SMC? Just a wild guess, but maybe there is a throttling curve that has maximum allowable temperatures for each RPM state. Something which the SMC developers might be able to answer (in a github issue)...

Comment: @n1000 it reaches ~ 98 C. you might be right. it seems like changing something in smc sets the thermal limit to 70 C. i'll have to do some more tests.

Comment: I can imagine that SMC only let’s you choose a point on the throttling curve but not edit that curve. Finally, allow me to state the obvious here. Allowing a temperature >100C will probably fry your CPU within a matter of seconds. A better approach might really be to limit power usage with tools like Volta and TurboBoostSwitcher. That is what I do to keep the noise down. Also cleaning out dust etc. might help.

Comment: @n1000  you are right. TurboBoostSwitcher helps somewhat. but still this makes me not want to buy a new macbook. there is a big difference between 70 C 90C and >100C. i've tested it without smc. and the same thing happens. it just takes longer for the macbook to reach 98C, the fans go nuts, then it slowly throttles the clock until the temp stays below 70C constantly. the fans still go nuts and stay nuts. somehow once it reaches almost 100C it sets the max temp to 70C.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92699/discussion-between-n1000-and-swisswiss).

Answer (score 1):

That sounds most probably like an old Mac, which will not go very fast anyway these days.

But the symptoms really can describe a few things of underlying problems.

- misconfiguration: look at the programs installed and delete what's unneeded, especially background applications (make a clean install ot the OS if all else fails)
- SMC settings got confused: perform an SMC-reset
- aging hardware: the thermal grease could be bad by now and might need replacement (try the other options first)
- being dirty: if the grills for the fans are clogged (most probable here) just open the case, clean it out.

Comment: i might try a fresh install. that seems like the only plausible fix.
hardware issues are most likely not the cause here, since the throttling happens at 70C and 70C seems like a software set max.

Comment: @swisswiss It wouldn't hurt to just look inside and examine the fans. HW that old *will* have dust inside and when the airflow (suboptimal in 2011 anyway) gets degraded then the sensor readings tell you not as much as you'd like.

Comment: i did open it just now and remove some dust. it didn't have much since i do that every year or so. still it seems to me the fans work quite well. they manage to bring down the temp from 90 to below 70 in a few seconds but they are extremely noisy.